# Tabbed components in React.js HTML include

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, include, react-tabs

I am just currently learning React.js and I am trying to work on a simple project that can have some really heavy body content but I have to keep them in one page, so I chose tabbed components as a possible solution.

So what I'm planning is to put the tab contents into separate HTMLs and just `include` them into the main page hidden until their tab option is clicked, but does this mean that the HTMLs will only be loaded into the app once the tab option is clicked?

Normally I would think that the separate HTMLs would be loaded at the same time the main page is loaded, but using React.js, maybe the functionality is different?

Can someone please clarify this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A single page application is generally "loaded" immediately, and the views change based on interaction. So if you properly set up your layout, the content will be interpreted when you load the page.

What you are calling HTMLs is properly called Components. Everything in React is based on JavaScript. You would store your components in JavaScript files that end in .js not .html, and then a JavaScript function would return your JSX Component as its return value, which will trigger the DOM to reload.